# window store 10 universal app development

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-store

After install VS 2015 community version, do I need to install any additional components for Windows 10 universal store app development? And how could I check if my VS 2015 community version is ready for Windows 10 universal store app development? This is what I see and it seems only win 8.1 related options are available?[image]

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to install the Windows 10 SDK.

[image]

There two versions of the Windows 10 SDK. The 10.0.10240 SDK which was released in July 2015, and the 10.0.10568 SDK which was released in November 2015. The next version of the SDK, which is codenamed "Redstone" will be available in the next few months. The right thing to do is to install both of them.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, if I just need to use .net native tool chain in VS 2015 community version, which version of Windows 10 SDK do you recommend? If you could provide a link to the SDK, it will be great. :)

Comment: BTW, Jerry, from your screen snapshot, it seems you upgrade from Visual Studio 2015 community version directly to install Win 10 SDK feature? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jerry, mark your reply as answer. Have a nice day.